# How to track mysql queries of different users with complete data and time

Tags: mysql

I want to track all mysql queries run by the users in my database.

Is there any way to alter SHOW PROFILE option where i can log my queries with the user ID??

Give me some suggestions on how to track the queries.
Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303994/log-all-queries-in-mysql

Comment: More like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585552/monitoring-queries-of-a-mysql-user although I don't get the reference to `SHOW PROFILE`, since it's information are specific to the *current* session where you *know* what queries are executed.